# Google Analytics v4 not working in Android App

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

So I followed this ( http://java.dzone.com/articles/working-google-analytics-api ) tutorial because I need Google Analytics in my application but I can't see anything in my GA Account. I put my log below.

```
09-13 21:15:05.906  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-13 21:15:06.006  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {426e9320}
09-13 21:15:06.006  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
09-13 21:15:06.006  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
09-13 21:15:06.016  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
09-13 21:15:06.016  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope E/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
09-13 21:15:06.037  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
09-13 21:15:06.147  31278-31298/com.rivert.unlockscope W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
09-13 21:15:06.257  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Loading Tracker config values.
09-13 21:15:06.257  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] trackingId loaded: UA-XXXXXXXX-2
09-13 21:15:06.257  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] sample frequency loaded: 100.0
09-13 21:15:06.257  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: [Tracker] auto activity tracking loaded: true
09-13 21:15:06.257  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: ExceptionReporter created, original handler is com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler
09-13 21:15:06.257  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Uncaught exceptions will be reported to Google Analytics.
09-13 21:15:06.267  31278-31312/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[client_id_fetcher,5,main]: Storing clientId.
09-13 21:15:06.297  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ ==> onReceive: s=0, m=1, n=h2w, sb=true
09-13 21:15:06.297  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope D/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ reportUpdate: state=0, devices=[Speakerphone, Headset earpiece]
09-13 21:15:06.327  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-13 21:15:06.337  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
09-13 21:15:06.387  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@426ea908 time:157709721
09-13 21:15:06.667  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope E/qdutils﹕ FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
09-13 21:15:07.738  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.", source: http://test.unlockscope.com/ (5)
09-13 21:15:11.242  31278-31311/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
09-13 21:15:11.252  31278-31311/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }
09-13 21:15:11.252  31278-31311/com.rivert.unlockscope I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
09-13 21:15:11.252  31278-31311/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
09-13 21:15:11.262  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@42779be0
09-13 21:15:11.262  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
09-13 21:15:11.262  31278-31278/com.rivert.unlockscope V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Few tips though: 1) Filter your log by `GAV4` (= Google analytics V4). 2) You shouldn't mention the tracking ID (`trackingId loaded: UA-5462XXXX-2`). 3) Did you just create the analytics account before testing the code? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867128/google-analytics-v4-data-not-showing-on-dashboard) you need to wait a few days before the account activates (meaning that if this was really the problem, it should work for you by now).

Comment: Thank :d. I'll keep that in mind for my future questions :d. I can see my data in analytics now but without the real time view, I don't know why.